# Issues while assigning the foreign key

Tags: php, mysql

I created a table named as "Projects". I wanted to create a foreign key "c_id" in this table but I am facing the following error message.

The error message is given below .

SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE `Projects` (
`p_id` INT( 150 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`project_name` VARCHAR( 500 ) NOT NULL ,
`c_id` INT( 150 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
INDEX ( `c_id` )
) ENGINE = MYISAM
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Whats the reason behind it?
Any help?

Thnx in advance....

Comment: The reason behind it that you can have **only one auto column and it must be defined as key**. It doesn't get clearer than that.

Answer (score 4):

You have two `auto_increment`. Try this instead:

```
CREATE TABLE Projects( 
    p_id INT( 150 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    project_name VARCHAR( 500 ) NOT NULL, 
    c_id INT( 150 ) NOT NULL, 
    INDEX ( c_id ) 
) ENGINE = MYISAM
```

`AUTO_INCREMENT` do it only for the p_id

Comment: nice that it helps you , make sure to accept the answer @user189998

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You must use InnDB as well as only 1 AUTO INCREMENT

```
CREATE TABLE Projects ( p_id INT( 150 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY , project_name VARCHAR( 500 ) NOT NULL , c_id INT( 150 ) NOT NULL , INDEX ( c_id ) ) ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have only one column with AUTO_INCREMENT per table. Remove it from c_id and try again

Answer (score 0):

use

```
CREATE TABLE Projects ( p_id INT( 150 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY , project_name VARCHAR( 500 ) NOT NULL , c_id INT( 150 ) NOT NULL  , INDEX ( c_id ) ) ENGINE = MYISAM
```

There should be only one AUTO_INCREMENT